# Visual Studio: Building in Debug mode but the files still built in Release folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a solution in Visual Studio.

I changed the build mode of the solution to be `Release`, and all output files of the solution were built in `example\example\Release\` folder. That's expected and fine. Then again I changed the mode to be `Debug`, but the files are still built in `example\example\Release\` folder.

I need the output files to be built in `bin\x86\Debug\` folder. How can I achieve this?
Is the solution corrupted or something like that? Should I recreate the solution? 
Any way to find the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If multiple projects are present in a solution with different output folders and dependencies, manually changing the output folder from default folder to a different or expected folder resolves the issue.